# @GetGeneratedKeys null when returning entire row after update

Tags: java, jdbc, h2, psql, jdbi

Trying to return an entire row after performing `@SqlUpdate`on a single row but I keep getting `null` response after the result has been mapped. I'm trying to follow example from [here](http://jdbi.org/#__getgeneratedkeys)

DAO has method

```
@SqlUpdate("UPDATE table SET status = :status WHERE id = :id")
@GetGeneratedKeys(ResultObject.class)
String updateTableStatus(@Bind("status") String status, @Bind("id") String id);
ResultObject updateStatus(@Bind("status") String status, @Bind("id") String id);
```

The mapper implements `ResultSetMapper<ResultObject>` 
and overrides `ResultObject map(int index, ResultSet r, StatementContext ctx) throws SQLException`

Is it not possible to return entire modified row with `@GetGeneratedKeys` as I see it returning ResultSetMapper. What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: I see two methods in your example code, but only one of them is annotated. Are you expecting the annotations to apply to both methods?

Answer (score 0):

User the returning syntax. A query returning the entire row would look like:

"UPDATE table SET status = :status WHERE id = :id returning *"

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/dml-returning.html

Comment: Is that an alternative to @GetGeneratedKeys ?

Comment: I had to add SqlQuery vs above SqlUpdate and custom mapper using @Mapper. Yet I get org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement wherein UPDATE Query has  "RETURNING[*] * " already appended